# How to use "MATCH.. CREATE UNIQUE.." with neography

Tags: neo4j, neography

I'm trying to write an importer script that will take a MySQL resultset and add nodes and relationships in my Neo4J DB. To simplify things, my resultset has the following fields:

- application_id
- amount
- application_date
- account_id

I want to create a node with `Application` label with the `application_id`, `amount`, `application_date` fields and another node with `Account` label with `account_id` field and a relationship between them.

My SQL query is from the applications table so I'm not afraid of dups there, but an account_id can appear more than once and I obviously don't want to create multiple nodes for that.

I'm using neography (but willing to switch if there is something simpler). What would be the best (easiest) way to achieve that?
My script will drop the database before it starts so no leftovers to take care of.

Should I create an index before and use `create_unique_node`?
I think I can do what I want in cypher using "MATCH .. CRAETE UNIQUE..", what's the equivalent of that in neography? I don't understand how `index_name` gets into the equation...
Should I or should I not define the constraint on Account?

Many thanks, 
It's my first time with graph DBs so apologies if I miss a concept here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, it looks like you should use the constraints that come with Neo4j 2.0 : http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-constraints.html#constraints-create-uniqueness-constraint

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (account:ACCOUNT) ASSERT account.account_id IS UNIQUE

Then you can use the MATCH .. CREATE UNIQUE clauses for all your inserts. You can use neography to submit the cypher queries, see the examples here: https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/wiki/Scripts-and-queries

Comment: do you know if there is any syntax in neography that does 'match' and 'create unique'? Or I have to use 'execute query'?

Comment: Use the "execute_query" with your cypher query as a parameter. Neography is just a wrapper around the REST end point of Neo4j, it doesn't have additional features.